# 複数の論理CPU間で、キャッシュメモリが共有されている/共有されていないという情報は、どのようにして確認できますか？

Tags: linux, cpu

## 背景

[［試して理解］Linuxのしくみ](https://gihyo.jp/book/2018/978-4-7741-9607-7)の4章「プロセススケジューリング」を読んでいます。

## 質問

P68では、複数の論理CPUで`sched`を実行する際、`taskset`コマンドで以下のように指定しています。

```
$ taskset -c 0,4 ./sched {process_num} 100 1
```

`taskset -c 0,1`ではなく`taskset -c 0,4`である理由を、次のように説明していました。

> なぜCPU0とCPU1ではなく、CPU0とCPU4なのかというと、簡単に言えば、この2つの論理CPUは6章において述べるキャッシュメモリを共有していないなどの理由によって、独立性が高いため、schedプログラムの性能測定に適しているからです。皆さんがこのプログラムを試す際は、論理CPU0と、番号が「論理CPU数/2」であるものを選べば、おおむねうまくいきます。

著者のマシンでは、8個の論理CPUが認識されています。

CPU0とCPU1がキャッシュメモリを共有していること、CPU0とCPU4がキャッシュメモリを共有していないことは、どのように確認できるのでしょうか？
参考になるサイトなどあれば、教えていただきたいです。

論理CPUの性質？はどれも同じだと思っていたので、「このペアは独立性が低い/高い」という事実に、驚きました。

## 補足:私の端末環境

#### lscpu

```
$ lscpu
アーキテクチャ:                      x86_64
CPU 操作モード:                      32-bit, 64-bit
バイト順序:                          Little Endian
Address sizes:                       36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU:                                 4
オンラインになっている CPU のリスト: 0-3
コアあたりのスレッド数:              2
ソケットあたりのコア数:              2
ソケット数:                          1
NUMA ノード数:                       1
ベンダー ID:                         GenuineIntel
CPU ファミリー:                      6
モデル:                              42
モデル名:                            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz
ステッピング:                        7
CPU MHz:                             899.454
CPU 最大 MHz:                        3500.0000
CPU 最小 MHz:                        800.0000
BogoMIPS:                            5582.03
仮想化:                              VT-x
L1d キャッシュ:                      64 KiB
L1i キャッシュ:                      64 KiB
L2 キャッシュ:                       512 KiB
L3 キャッシュ:                       4 MiB
NUMA ノード 0 CPU:                   0-3
Vulnerability Itlb multihit:         KVM: Vulnerable
Vulnerability L1tf:                  Mitigation; PTE Inversion
Vulnerability Mds:                   Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
Vulnerability Meltdown:              Mitigation; PTI
Vulnerability Mmio stale data:       Not affected
Vulnerability Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
Vulnerability Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
Vulnerability Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Retpolines, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP conditional, RSB filling
Vulnerability Srbds:                 Not affected
Vulnerability Tsx async abort:       Not affected
フラグ:                              fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch
                                     _perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x
                                     2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts m
                                     d_clear flush_l1d
```

#### ハイパースレッドが有効であることの確認

```
$ sudo dmidecode -t processor | grep -E '(Core Count|Thread Count)'
    Core Count: 2
    Thread Count: 4
```

#### cpuinfo

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x2f
cpu MHz     : 858.809
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 5582.03
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x2f
cpu MHz     : 821.302
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 5582.03
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x2f
cpu MHz     : 845.573
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 5582.03
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 42
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2640M CPU @ 2.80GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x2f
cpu MHz     : 826.173
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 5582.03
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: Intel CPU の Hyper Threading Temporary 機能(HTT)に関する事でしょうか？ おそらく、その書籍のどこかに HTT に関する説明があるのだろうと推察します。そこに物理 CPU と論理 CPU の違いやキャッシュ機構との関連について言及されているかもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 論理CPUの性質？はどれも同じだと思っていたので、「このペアは独立性が低い/高い」という事実に、驚きました。

[Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 3A: System Programming Guide, Part 1](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html) で触れられています。

- Package

  - Core

    - SMT (Hyper-Threading)

の階層があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> CPU0とCPU1がキャッシュメモリを共有していること、CPU0とCPU4がキャッシュメモリを共有していないことは、どのように確認できるのでしょうか？

実際に共有しているかどうかはそれぞれのプロセッサアーキテクチャを確認する必要があります。しかし、プロセッサは３次キャッシュまで持ち、どこかしら共有している可能性があるため、独立性が欲しいのであれば、上記階層の中から単純に一番遠いプロセッサを選択すればよいかと。
Intelプロセッサには`APIC ID`というものが振られており、

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

で参照することができます。加えて`APIC ID`だけでなくそれを解析した結果として、`physical id`や`core id`なども出力されます。（Package IDは出てこなかった…）
参考としてうちのPCは6core 12threadですが、processor 0と6が`physical id==0`、`core id==0`でキャッシュ共有など距離が近い存在でした。（つまり質問者さんが参照された書籍と真逆です）

Comment: 参考情報として私の端末情報を記載しました。私の環境は2core, 4threadです。例えば、論理CPU0と論理CPU2のペアはcore idが0と1で異なるので、論理CPU0と論理CPU1のペアよりは独立性が高いと言えるのでしょうか？

Comment: @yuji38kwmt はい、2core環境であればcore idが0と1で異なっていればより独立性が高いと判断できます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

一言で言ってしまえば論理CPUとの性質をすべて同じにしなければならないという規則も原理もないのでCPUメーカーがCPUの性能を高めるために色々と工夫をしているからですね。キャッシュメモリの共有情報の取得については私は知らないのでそっちがメインの質問であればここで読み終えてください。キャッシュメモリ以外にも論理CPU0には機能Aがあるが論理CPU5にはないなんてこともありますね。

ほかの人も言及しているようにintel製CPUかつHTT搭載CPUを前提にした説明かと思います。
HTTはSMTの一種でCPUがOSに対しCPUのコアを二つ以上に見せる手法です。この場合論理CPUと物理CPUが2:1で紐づくので論理CPU0と1論理、論理CPU2と論理CPU3といった具合にキャッシュを共有することになります。まあキャッシュ以外にもいろいろ共有しているのですがそこは枝葉のため省略します。
問題の書籍の出版時点ではパソコン向けCPUにはHTT搭載で1物理コアが2論理コアに見えるものとHTT非搭載で1物理コアが1論理コアに見えるものの二種類のみでした。したがって書籍に記載された方法で別の物理コアに対しもろもろアサインできることになります。
まあ細かいこと言いだすと当時も独立性以外にCPUのコアごとに最高動作周波数が違うなどありましたが。またサーバのことを言い出せば複数ソケット対応のサーバなんて珍しくないのでメモリ空間も物理的に切り離されてたりしますけども。
おまけに現代的なCPUはコアをヘテロジニアス化してしまったのでパソコンでもコアによって処理速度が全然違ったりしますね。(EコアPコアとかbig.LITTLEとか)